# Is this kind of log system harmful to the hard disk?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, logging

Recently I'm learning the web development and I found the applications will write their running
logs into `/tmp/appname/logs/a.log` or `/tmp/appname/logs/a.log.1` with the following format:

```
{"message": "do task a", "level": "INFO", "timestamp": "2020-11-15T02:09:23.049742Z", "logger": "service1"}
{"message": "do task b", "level": "INFO", "timestamp": "2020-11-15T02:09:27.646271Z", "logger": "service2"}
{"message": "do task c", "level": "INFO", "timestamp": "2020-11-15T02:09:28.055893Z", "logger": "redis-service"}
{"message": "do task d", "level": "INFO", "timestamp": "2020-11-15T02:09:32.651385Z", "logger": "nginx-service"}
{"message": "do task e", "level": "INFO", "timestamp": "2020-11-15T02:09:33.062060Z", "logger": "rest-service"}
```

From the timestamps, we can see that these events for the tasks are nearly running at the same time. So these applications record their status into these log files.

My question is, there are so many applications (or processes) concurrently writing the log file at the same time, is this harmful to the hard disk in which the log file saved, because of the heavy write operations? The hard disk will do a heavy task to write the logs.

I remember that there is a `flush` operation to commit the content in the buffer to do the final disk-write. But I worry about the hard disk has a heavy load. Is there any good programming principles to protect the hard disks? I think one way is to use the memory as the cache, first write the logs in the memory and when the buffer is full, then do a real disk-write. This will save the hard disk's life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any disk, HDD or SSD, can easily withstand one write every few seconds.

Typical disks are conceived to withstand daily traffic measured in gigabytes,
so these few lines will have no effect on your disk's life expectancy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind answer! Yeah, I understand the modern hard disk can handle these simple cases. The log in the question are just as an example. When the system is running in high-concurrency, the there will be many concurrency `disk writes` to the log file.

Comment: Any operating system reads and writes to the disk all the time, even when the computer is idle. My advice is not to worry.

Comment: Yeah, thank you sir!